# How do I create a kickstart image file from a running RHEL 7.6 server

Tags: rhel7

We have two identical production servers that are both running RHEL 7.6, with custom applications, on two isolated networks. We are wanting to add eight more of these servers to eight more isolated networks. The hardware is identical for all servers as well as the users and groups, and custom applications. The only difference will be the IP addressing. Is there a way to make an image of one of the running servers to use as a kickstart for the new servers?